# Looking for a sound system

Tags: audio, speakers, sound-system

I'm looking for a sound system for my garage (2-car Extended with an extra room). I want it to be strong enough to fill the space with sound over the top of whatever i may be doing at the time within reason, but not something so strong that I get the police called on me for noise ordinance violations. I'm looking for a recommendation (Which are usually not allowed on stack exchange) Or an external link for a site that will help me calculate what I'm looking for. This I feel like is within standards in the stack because other people looking for the same thing could use this question to answer their own recommendation inquiries. I appreciate you guys!!

I have a 30'x30' Garage, I don't need my neighbor's across town hearing the music, but I would like to be able to hear it over whatever I may be doing without stressing the machinery. Mid-level needs to be loud enough to be heard over a small air compressor (1-2gallon). The sound system will be either located in a central location as there's a small shelving unit there, or if there's a way to connect all of them to the computer or phone via Bluetooth uplink, as well as multiple speakers, they'll be spread around the edges focusing the sound towards that central location..  I googled the compressor and it said it was around 75 dB so if the middle setting is that loud or slightly louder I'll be very interested. I hope this helps get the ambiguity resolved. Anything further please let me know!!

Comment: This isn't on topic either here or Sound Design, where you cross-posted it. There is nowhere on SE for HiFi recommendations, nor any way to answer such a nebulous request.

Comment: This actually looks on-topic for this site, but I'm not sure. I will let the other reviewers decide

Comment: Agreed, this is on topic but the question needs more detail. Requirements are "nebulous" and impossible to recommend something right now.

Comment: Romen & @Irsu85 - right from the top of the on topic page - "Hardware" is not an all-encompassing term. We can help you if you're looking for a recommendation for hardware that is "an electronic item that is, interfaces with, or connects to a computer to operate".

Comment: @Tetsujin, The sound system could be plugged in to a computer; So it is on topic just like asking for computer speakers would be. People have asked for much less relevant stuff here without the question being closed for being off topic. I already flagged the question though because it's impossible to recommend a sound system if the question doesn't provide objective requirements. OP needs to tell us more about the garage size and layout, what kind of volume level is "strong enough" for them, and what features & connections the sound system needs too.

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: JFL Flip4 or Flip5; use your phone or tablet over wifi and stream pandora or whatever and bluetooth to the speaker.  Multiple speakers could be used. all connected via bluetooth; there are many but JBL is one of the better ones.